# Wordpress - ACF field rewrite slug issue

Tags: php, wordpress, function, plugins, advanced-custom-fields

So I am having an issue that I have spent just way too long on. Basically I am getting this error: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_current_screen() in /home1/teamv/public_html/wp-content/plugins/advanced-custom-fields-pro/api/api-helpers.php on line 3252`

When I run this code which is in my functions.php

```
// For hidden Fieldss
function acf_review_before_save_post($post_id) {
    if (empty($_POST['acf']))
        return;

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $value = $_POST['acf']['field_578b7b3470e26']; // Address
    $_POST['acf']['_post_title'] = '( '.$_POST['acf']['field_578ce02b9f472'].' ) - ' . $value['address'];
    $_POST['acf']['_post_content'] = $value['address'];
    $_POST['acf']['field_578f32d3ff97e'] = $value['lat'];
    $_POST['acf']['field_578f32e8ff97f'] = $value['lng'];

    $_POST['acf']['field_578e1d7b97981'] = $current_user->display_name;
    return $post_id;
}
add_action('acf/pre_save_post', 'acf_review_before_save_post', -1); 

//Change things when saave for ACF
function my_acf_save_post( $post_id ) {

    $new_slug = $_POST['acf']['field_578ce02b9f472'];
    $new_slug = sanitize_title($new_slug);
    $new_slug .= '-'.$post_id;

    $my_post = array(
      'ID'           => $post_id,
      'post_name'   => $new_slug,
    );

    wp_update_post( $my_post );
}

// run after ACF saves the $_POST['acf'] data
add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_post', 1);
```

What I am trying to do, is update both the post title, content, the custom Lat, Lng field for my google map, adding a user, which is all working fine, however, when I get to updating the post slug, i get the error mentioned above. I just can't figure out what on earth is wrong. Can someone please help me out, I would really appreciate it :) By the way, this is specifically an Advanced Custom Fields issue. Documentation here > https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acfsave_post/

Comment: Oh and it seems to happen when wp_update_post() is called..

Comment: Someone pleas help ?